# dimension of intersection of subspaces, one of which of dimension $n-1$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $H$ be a linear subspace of dimension $n-1$ of a linear space $V$ of dimension $n$.

Let $W$ be some subspace of $V$.

Show one of the following holds:

1. $W \subseteq H$ or
2. $\dim(W \cap H) = \dim(W) - 1$

This makes a lot of sense to me, as if there is some element in w that isn't in a largest subspace of V, then one of its dimensions can't be spanned by any of the vectors in the basis of $H$, thus its dimension is at most $\dim(W) - 1$.

It is intuitive, but I can't come up with a proof...

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: use the Grassman formula for dimension of $H + W$

$$\dim (H+W)+\dim (H\cap W)=\dim (W) + \dim (H)$$

If $W \subset H$ then $H + W=H$, otherwise it is all the ambient space $V$.

Edit: suppose $H+W=V$, then $\dim (H+W)=n$ and by Grassman formula:

$$n + \dim (H\cap W)=\dim (W) + \dim (H)=\dim (W) + n-1$$

Comment: sorry, I don't see how $H+W$ helps me here... could you explain please?

Comment: Is it more clear, now?